# Auto choosing low latency network for proxy

Tags: azure, web-services, networking, ansible, latency

I have web server A and server B in different country , they have a very high latency when connecting with each other.
So i built proxy (include server C1,C2,C3) to reduce network latency, but C1, C2, C3 is not stable for sometime, 
now i'm trying to configure this proxy to auto choose the lowest latency server, 
could Ansible Network Automation or Azure Traffic Manager or something else 
solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Traffic Manager can do this work for you. If you put this in front of your web application servers you can then choose one of these two profiles to route them based on location:

1. Performance - this will route the user to the endpoint closest in terms of network latency
2. Geographic - This will route the user to the closest location based on their location determined from DNS

If performance is what you are concerned about then I would suggest using the performance option.

Comment: Is there an off-platform solution? Still want to know if  Ansible Network Automation could work.

Comment: Any sort of performance-based routing solution will work, it does not need to be Azure specific. All you are doing here is DNS routing. You can use Traffic managed with sites hosted anywhere, so I imagine other services will allow you to do the same. I don't have experiece with Ansibles option.